# Help exiting Emergency Mode with unmountable LVM system

Tags: fedora, boot

[image: LVM & mount]

My `/` partition in a Fedora Server 32 system was running out so I grew the volume using Cockpit. It seemed the problem ended there but the system rebooted into Emergency Mode and I cannot get it out of it.

I wasn't even aware it was an LVM system which I avoid at all costs, `/etc/fstab` does not exist, I assume because of LVM. `mount -a` then `xfs_repair -f /dev/mapper/fedora-root` or `xfs_repair -f /dev/fedora/root` returns an error saying I need to mount the filesystems. `fsck`... not a chance.

Based on the information I've been able to get guessing my way by tab-completing commands is that the logical volume was resized but the file system wasn't. How can I do that? I mean, if that'll get me out of Emergency Mode.

The commands set is very limited, there's no `fdisk`, `gparted`, `df`, there's not even `vim`, only `vi`. There's `xfs_db`, `xfs_metadump` and `xfs_repair`. I'm not 100% sure is a XFS volume but I favor that over **ext4**. Then again, I don't go for **LVM** either, clearly this system wasn't put together like usual.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no `LVM` expert, far from it, but I have `/etc/fstab` and it contains several references to `LVM` logical volumes.  Perhaps you need `/etc/fstab`?  In addition, I also know next to nothing about `XFS`, but aren't those expandable, via `xfs_growfs`, but not shrinkable (may need to backup data, re-partition, and restore data)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand LVM volumes, you generally want to use LVM to do so. Typically if you need to extend the physical volume to match the limits set in your partition table you would enter lvm and use **pvresize** to do so. Then to extend a logical volume, i.e. /dev/mapper/fedora-root you would use **lvextend** within the lvm console. Following that, as Fedora,Centos, and RedHat use XFS by default, you would mount said partition, if not already mounted. And then use xfs_growfs. If you are lacking an /etc/fstab in emergency mode, you most likely need to manually mount your logical volumes onto /mnt (or a similar directory you would like to use.

```
#mount /dev/mapper/fedora-root /mnt
#xfs_repair /mnt
```

If you do have to rollback to a newer image or do a reinstall, I would recommend you do not use alternate tools to resize LVM volumes.